# Propriedade contendo apenas o atributo KeyAttribute resultando em coluna auto-incremento no banco de dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, auto-incremento

Se não me engano, isso deve ter vindo na versão 6.1.1 do EntityFramework e não era assim nas versões anteriores.

Acredito que uma coluna só se tornava autoincremento quando o atributo `DatabaseGenerated` era declarado com a assinatura `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`.

Tenho uma classes simples, assim:

```
public class Municipio
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Uf { get; set; }
}
```

Veja que a propriedade `Id` está declarada com o atributo `KeyAttribute` apenas. Porém, está sendo gerada uma coluna *Autoincrement*.

[image: Amostragem da coluna sendo gerada como Identity]

Como impedir que isso aconteça?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Acredito que uma coluna só se tornava autoincremento quando o atributo `DatabaseGenerated` era declarado com a assinatura `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`.

Não necessariamente. Desde o Entity Framework 5 o uso do atributo é opcional.

### Como impedir que isso aconteça?

Usando `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`.